# Defining a key binding in ST3 to delete all comments in a file

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3, key-bindings, keymapping

I heard you can set a key binding to handle deleting all comments in a file in Sublime Text 3. However, I'm having some difficulty understanding it though the [Sublime Text Docs](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/customization/key_bindings.html).

Any suggestions how to set this up in the `default (OSX).sublime-keymap` file?

Here's what I have so far (though it does not work)...

```
{ "keys": ["command+esc"], "command": "find", "args": {"characters": "^#.*\n"}, "replace all", ""}
```

Any input on how to fix this to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

i'd suggest using gulp (via nodeJS) for something like this which will let you comment your build version files and not have to worry about production.